# Integrate spring session into websocket for Http session clean up

Tags: spring-websocket, spring-session

I have a Spring Boot websocket server deployed on Heroku and need help to properly implement authentication and session management in order to clean up/invalidate the authenticated sessions when the user disconnects from the server.

My `SecurityFilterChain` is configured to not allow more than one session per user, so if the first is not properly invalidated when disconnecting or after some time of inactivity (e.g. connection dropped), the user will not be able to reconnect.

```
 @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz.anyRequest().authenticated())
        .httpBasic(withDefaults())
        .sessionManagement(session -> session
            .maximumSessions(1)
            .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true));
    return http.build();
  }
```

As a first workaround I tried setting `server.servlet.session.timeout=1m` so anyway after 1 minute of inactivity the Http session is invalidated. I have a heartbeat in place so expected that to be effective in keeping the session alive until user disconnects, but this is not the case. After 1 minute the connection drops.

**Why does the heartbeat not keeping the Http session alive?**

The heartbeat works for what concerns Heroku: I have set `server.servlet.session.timeout=10m` on the server, the client application stays in idle for minutes without having the connection cut by Heroku, which normally would occur after 55 seconds.

So far I configured spring security to use basic http authentication backed by a postgres relational database.

Now I am trying with Spring Session to achieve better control on session life cycle, but I cannot have it working.

**Is spring session the mandatory/state of art solution for my need?**

I get the following error:

```
Field sessionRepository in org.springframework.session.web.socket.config.annotation.AbstractSessionWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer required a bean of type 'org.springframework.session.SessionRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.session.SessionRepository' in your configuration.
```

My server configuration is the following

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class EngineConfig extends AbstractSessionWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer<Session> {

  @Override
  public void configureStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint(SRV_ENDPOINT);
  }

  @Override
  public void configureWebSocketTransport(WebSocketTransportRegistration registry) {
    registry.setMessageSizeLimit(MESSAGE_SIZE_LIMIT);
    registry.setSendBufferSizeLimit(SEND_BUFFER_SIZE_LIMIT);
    registry.setSendTimeLimit(SEND_TIME_LIMIT);
  }

  @Override
  public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker(MSG_BROKER_PREFIX)
        .setHeartbeatValue(new long[]{HEART_BEAT_TIME, HEART_BEAT_SEND})
        .setTaskScheduler(heartBeatScheduler());
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes(APP_DESTINATION_PREFIX);
  }

  @Bean
  public TaskScheduler heartBeatScheduler() {
    return new ConcurrentTaskScheduler();
  }

}
```

The `application.properties` is

```
server.servlet.session.timeout=10m
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/xxxx
spring.datasource.username=xxxx
spring.datasource.password=xxxx
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.session.store-type=jdbc
spring.session.jdbc.initialize-schema=embedded
spring.session.jdbc.schema=classpath:org/springframework/session/jdbc/schema-@@platform@@.sql
spring.session.jdbc.table-name=SPRING_SESSION
```

So far I based the code on Spring official documentation for [spring session](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/reference/index.html), [HttpSession integration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/reference/http-session.html) and finally [websocket integration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/reference/2.7/web-socket.html)

Any suggestion appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure of what solved. Upgraded gradle plugin to version 3.1.1 `'id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.1'` and changed property in `application.configuration` to `spring.session.jdbc.initialize-schema=always`. This combination fixed the issue.